# Event.getX() gets wrong values when using onTouchListener

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener

Here is the first code:

```
btn1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
                int x_cursor = (int) event.getX();
                x_initial_touch = event.getX();

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                         x_initial_touch = event.getX();
                         break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                       System.out.println(event.getX())
                       btn1.animate().translationX(x_cursor - x_initial_touch ).setDuration(0);
                       break;
                    
                }
                    return false;
                }
        });
```

Here is the secoond code:

```
btn1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
                int x_cursor = (int) event.getX();
                x_initial_touch = event.getX();

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                         x_initial_touch = event.getX();
                         break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                       System.out.println(event.getX())
                       any_other_button.animate().translationX(x_cursor - x_initial_touch ).setDuration(0);
                       break;
                    
                }
                    return false;
                }
        });
```

In first code, when i drag the button to the left, the values that are printed are: 57
56
57
55
57
54
57
53
and so on...

And in second code, when i drag the button to the left, the values that are printed are:
57
56
55
54
53
52
51
50
and so on...(which is very good, and what i want).
My question is why in the first code, when I try to drag a button by touching and dragging IT the event.getX() is making some steps back and then continue.
I am asking this because as you can figure the button won't move smooth and it will come back for a milisec to start position.
Hope you understant what I want to say.

***EDIT***
I've solve the issue using *event.getRawX();* instead of *event.getX();*

Answer (score 0):

Your `x_cursor` and `x_initial_touch` are both equal to `event.getX()`, so the argument of your `translationX` call is always zero, which resets the initial position. Thus, after each move you get one more event which corresponds to resetting your initial position. If you translate `any_other_button`, then it will not send the event to `btn1` when its position is reset, so you don't see the interleaving 57's in the second case.